# Determinant of $N \times N$ matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have the following matrix which I need to find the determinant of. I am not too sure of how to proceed. Here is my working so far.

\begin{equation}
\det(\boldsymbol J (E_i) - \lambda \mathbb I ) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 -\lambda   & \dots  & \phi_{1i}  &  \dots   & 0  \\
\vdots   &  \ddots  & \vdots & & \vdots \\
-c_{i1} & \dots &  \color{red}{A_i -\lambda} & \dots & -c_{iN}\\
\vdots   &    & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots & \phi_{Ni} & \dots & A_N -\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The matrix has a diagonal given by $A_j -\lambda$. From the central red element there are vertically and horizontally non-zero elements. All other elements are zero exactly.

I am really not sure how to find the determinant from here and any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

For instance if $N$ where to equal 4 we might have the following case if $i=3$, 
\begin{equation}
\det(\boldsymbol J (E_i) - \lambda \mathbb I ) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
D_1   & 0  & V_1  &   0  \\
0  &  D_2 & V_2&0 \\
H_1 & H_2 &  D_3 & H_4\\
0  &   0 & V_4 & D_4  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: If from diagonal entries vertical /horizontal elements in that row/column are nonzero, that seems to go against the two $0$ entries upper right and lower left.

Comment: @coffeemath Apologies for my poor wording, please see the update!

Comment: So, wait, your original matrix is like $[[1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 5, 0, 6], [0, 0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 8, 0, 9]]$?

Comment: Could the upper right and lower left entries, now labeled as $0,$ also be nonzero in the case $i \neq 1,N$?

Comment: @DanUznanski No, so all diagonal elements are non-zero. In addition in the special case of the $i$th row and column we have non-zero elements too

Comment: Step 1: Change basis from $e_1, e_2, \ldots e_n$ to $e_i,  e_2, \ldots, e_1, \ldots e_n$, exchanging rows $1$ and $i$ and columns $1$ and $i$. Then the first row and column become nonzero, and the remainder of the matrix is diagonal.  That'll at least simplify the notation without changing the determinant.

Comment: So $[[1,0,2,0,0],[0,3,4,0,0],[5,6,7,8,9],[0,0,10,11,0],[0,0,12,0,13]]$

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you for your comment, from here how would I proceed?

Comment: You'd used the solution given by user1551, which is complete and correct. The solution does not say that the middle element of the matrix is zero, only that the middle entry of each of $u$ and $v$ is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit.** Let $B$ the submatrix obtained by deleting the $i$-th row and $i$-th column of the given matrix. Then the required determinant is the product of determinant of the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $B$ and $\det B$, i.e.
$$
\left(A_i-\lambda + \sum_{k\ne i}\frac{c_k\phi_{ki}}{A_k-\lambda}\right) \prod_{k\ne i}(A_k-\lambda).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a little difficult for me to understand, but does it hold for my edit? I just note that you say that the middle element has to be zero, this might not always be the case though?